# How do I make g++ 10 my default c++ compiler

Tags: g++

I am using 20.04 and I have g++ 10 installed, but when I use g++ --version it says 9.3. Also, I can't use any c++ 20 in my code in either IDE I use. Please let me know how I make g++ 10 the default. Thanks

Comment: Did you know you can set the `CXX` environment variable, and most build systems will inherit that configuration? If you're using a build system generator, like CMake, you'll need to export this in your environment when you run configuration.

Comment: What IDE do you use?

Comment: I use both CLion and Code::Blocks

Comment: I think i just need to know how to set the CXX environment variable then.

Comment: Well, I solved  the problem in a roundabout way, I upgraded to 21.04 and it set my default g++ to 10